# Replacing a specific pattern containing newline using sed

Tags: bash, sed, replace, newline

I was instructed to write a program in which a sub-program replaces all the `'\n|'` with `' |'`. I don't know of any method except `sed` which can be used for the purpose.

I used the following: `sed -uz 's#\n|# |#g' -`

The `z` flag separates the file using `null characters` so it worked but what if I have a complex regular expression and the file is a bit corrupted and contains null chars in between. `sed` will separate at that `null` character and my regex would be rendered useless.

All I want is a foolproof method to replace regex containing newlines.
(I am using bash in Linux)

Comment: even if your file contained ASCII NUL characters, this should work because you are replacing `\n|`, not NUL characters

Comment: for some other reason if you are looking for slurping entire file irrespective of NUL characters, you could use `perl -0777`

Comment: Ya, it would work in this particular case as I am replacing just `\n` but as I said, I want to know how to do it for any regex.

Comment: And, I am not much familiar with perl 

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182153/sed-read-whole-file-into-pattern-space-without-failing-on-single-line-input and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string